# Some questions about module dependency ordering in IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The thing is, I am reading the chapter about [**Sort dependencies**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.3/working-with-module-dependencies.html#sort-dependencies) in the official IDEA documentation.

There is a description like this：

"The order of dependencies is important as IntelliJ IDEA will process them in the same order as they are specified in the list."

"During compilation, the order of dependencies defines the order in which the compiler (javac) looks for classes to resolve the corresponding references. At runtime, this list defines the order in which the JVM searches for the classes."

o I created three modules (TestModule1, TestModule2, TestModule3) in IDEA and wanted to verify the accuracy of the above text by modifying the loading order of dependent modules. Therefore, I loaded the two modules TestModule2 and TestModule3 as dependencies of the TestModule1 module, and then I created an A.java file in TestModule2 with the following source code:

```
type java

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.show(B.getInstance());
    }

    public static void show(B b) {
        MyUtils.getClassName(b.getClass());
    }
}
```

Then a new B.java was created in TestModule3, its source code is as follows:

```
type java

public class B {
    public static B getInstance() {
        return new B();
    }


}
```

Then I created a new MyUtils.java in TestModule1. Its source code is as follows:

```
type java

public class MyUtils {
    public static void getClassName(Class<?> c) {
        System.out.println(c.getName());
    }
}
```

Then I have TestModule1 and TestModule3 in TestModule2 as its dependencies. At this point, I want to test my guess by adjusting their loading order! Because I know that the loading order of the classes in the classpath will affect the final running results of the program, but unfortunately no matter how I adjust them my program can run normally!

Could it be that the processing is done after all classes in the target module are loaded into the class path? If that's the case, what's the point of adjusting the loading order of modules?

I need a proof project that is effective enough to verify that this function works, thank you~

Comment: Try having two classes with the same name in both dependencies.

Comment: I'm so sorry! I don't understand, can you provide some specific demo code?

Comment: The order of the dependencies is important if there are dependencies providing the same fully qualified class names (like different versions of the same library). The order will control which version of the same class will be used.